# Change the border height in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the left border of siginimage to `40px`, but since the height of the signinimage is `25px`, the border height is also being set as `25px`.

```css
.top-header {
    float: left;
    border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#signinimage {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 25px; 
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img src="images/signinimage.png" class="top-header" id="signinimage">
```

Comment: No, the border covers the full side for which it is the border; unfortunately `<img>` elements don't offer the use of pseudo-elements and `box-shadow` would, again, be equal to the full height/length of the element. If you're able to wrap the `<img>` you might be able to make it work. Or, possibly, use an SVG.

Comment: unfortunately i'm not  familiar with svg. Just a beginner.

Comment: No, try using a pseudo element instead. Can set whatever height you want and position absolute it relative to the element

Comment: but <img> elements do not offer the use of pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches.

1. **Either create a container and put the image inside it**

> *In your question, you said you wanted to extend the border to the left
>   (but I mean that's just a matter of simple* `float:`, *but you can apply
>   this approach in general*

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}

#container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/QIsNrpM.png/>
</div>
```

2. **The other alternative, if you insist on using only one element instead of two, you can set the image as a `background-image` of a differently sized `div`**

```css
    #imganddiv {
      border: 3px solid black;
      width: 150px;
      height: 100px;
      
      background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/QIsNrpM.png');
      background-size: 100px 100px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: right center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="imganddiv"></div>
```

I personally prefer the first option as it's a bit more intuitive and generally considered a common practice on to how containers (elements inside elements) should be handled.

Comment: I'm up-voting largely because - in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728111/is-there-a-way-i-can-change-the-border-height-in-css?noredirect=1#comment88464315_50728111), above - I forgot the simplest alternative, to use the `<img>` as a background image (although that's not an ideal solution, given the accessibility problems it raises if the picture is content).

Answer (score 0):

To get a border taller than the image, you can wrap the image in a container, and apply the border to that container.

```css
.top-header{
  float: left;
  border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;

  /* Center the image vertically */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
 
#signinimage{
  height: 25px; 
  width: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-header">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/25/25" id="signinimage">
</div>
```